# Unexpected output using comparator

Tags: java, sorting

I have the following program

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] array = { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9 };
        Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<Integer>() {
            public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
                return i1 < i2 ? -1 : (i2 > i1 ? 1 : 0);
            }
        });
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

This gives me the output [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You test for i1 < i2, and, if it fails, you test NOT for i1 > i2, but for i2 > i1.

Change your comparator to

```
   return i1 < i2 ? -1 : (i1 > i2) ? 1 : 0;
```

ADDED

In an attempt to contribute something new to the two other answers that said the same thing and beat me to the punch, most of the wrapper classes have built in compareTo() methods to save you from any thought.  e.g., your comparator could just call Integer.compareTo(), i.e.

```
 return i1.compareTo(i2);
```

Comment: Probably should be using compareTo() anyway since those magic numbers don't look healthy; +1 for that.

Answer (score 6):

because `i1 < i2` is the same as `i2 > i1` - look what you've written in your compareTo method.

Answer (score 3):

```
i1 < i2 
i2 > i1
```

These are the same.