# Why does this sort in Java 1.8

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, timsort

Taken from Java Puzzlers by Joshua Bloch and Neal Gafter

```
import java.util.*;

public class BananaBread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] array = { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9 };
        Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<Integer>() {
            public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
                return i1 < i2 ? -1 : (i2 > i1 ? 1 : 0);
            }
        });
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

The expected behaviour is undefined and the text says that it returns [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9].  This is true up to Java Version 1.7.  However, in Java v. 1.8, the output is the sorted list.

I can see that Timsort is new in Java 1.8, but I'm not sure how the algorithm can function with an inconsistent comparator such as the one given above.  Any help or insight into how this can be would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Autoboxing issue? I would rather use `compareTo` from `Integer`.

Comment: It is the same code as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900871/unexpected-output-using-comparator. Doesn't cover the new Java 8 sorting though.

Comment: i1 < i2 vs. i2 > i1.... hmmm....... ;-)      I don't think "Undefined" means "Java must do the same thing with every version of Java."

Comment: G. Sylvie Davies, I agree, it shouldn't (and doesn't) work in Java 1.7 and earlier.  Java 1.8 is throwing me for a loop because it actually works and sorts the list.

Comment: this implies that in 1.8 it would work if the return was return 1 < i2 ? -1 : 0;

Comment: the following three give exactly the same answers as the example above: return i1 < i2 ? -1 : (i2 > i1 ? 0 : 1); _____ return i1 < i2 ? -1 : (i2 < i1 ? 0 : 1); ______   return i1 < i2 ? -1 : (i2 < i1 ? 1 : 0);

Comment: The comparator is fine if you compare items in the right order or only act when the result is < 0 like infact it does in http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/TimSort.java#292

Comment: No sources or anything, so I won't post an answer, but it could be because a combination of luckily correct array and implementation details mean that reporting > as == doesn't matter. Which version of Java are you using? (as in, where did you download it from?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java 8 uses a modied merge sort.  The key line it uses is

```
// From TimSort.binarySort
while (left < right) {
    int mid = (left + right) >>> 1;
    if (c.compare(pivot, a[mid]) < 0)  // compares for less than 0.
        right = mid;
    else
        left = mid + 1;
}
```

Note: it only cares about whether you return -1 or 0 (more specifically is < 0, true or false)

Your comparator is the same as

```
return i1 < i2 ? -1 : 0;
```

so in all the ways that matter for this code it's correct.

Note: if you change the code like this

```
return i1 > i2 ? +1 : 0;
```

It doesn't sort anything.

Comment: If you use VM arg `-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true` you can get the original merge sort. Someone lazily coded our comparator to do -1 and 0 and it took me forever to figure out why it stopped sorting when we migrated to JDK8.